# HTML5 Geolocation PHP alternative

Tags: php, html, geolocation, location

I tried to find a way to find user's location in PHP, but except IP-based solutions I haven't found anything.

My application tries to find users location, and then store it in a database, so HTML5 geolocation (+JavaScript) wouldn't be a solution, as the position can be altered.

Application => Location => Database.

Any solution or recommendation?

Comment: Can you explain more about why browser geolocation is unsuitable? If you mean that the user can fake their location, then yes - they have every right to. You should only attempt to get the user's location strictly on a consent basis. (If an accuracy of closest-city is acceptable, then use IP geolocation, but let users correct incorrect assumptions if they wish).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean in a regular website - or are you talking mobile devices here?

Comment: The application will be a mobile application, but based on web.

The user should not modify their position, as the application is strictly based on that.

Comment: I think browser geolocation or IP location are your only alternatives. There is no "verified location" service as far as I know - I think Android can read cell-tower location information, and so do a better job than IP location. It'd be hard to fake (certainly on an unrooted phone) but you can't do this in the browser. [This app](http://www.panix.com/~mpoly/android/antennas/r1.0/) does it, but the locations of cell towers is not entirely reliable.

Comment: Ask the users where they live ...

Comment: @halfer Well, Pokemon Go user can fake their location now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

I will use HTML5 geolocation (maybe implement some kind of client-side query verification) and if it won't be available I will use a public API on a ip-to-location serivce.